# ImportError: Could not import faiss python package

Tags: python

I am getting this error on python3.12 on M1 air

ImportError: Could not import faiss python package. Please install it with `pip install faiss-gpu` (for CUDA supported GPU) or `pip install faiss-cpu` (depending on Python version).

It suggests installing fairs-cpu and gpu and none of it works. Can someone help?

Here's the code that's being used

```
import streamlit as st
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import google.generativeai as palm
from langchain_community.embeddings import GooglePalmEmbeddings
from langchain_community.llms import GooglePalm
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"] = "***********************"

def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    return ''

def get_text_chunks(text):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=20)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    return chunks

def get_vector_store(text_chunks):
    embeddings = GooglePalmEmbeddings()
    vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    return vector_store

def get_conversational_chain(vector_store):
    llm=GooglePalm()
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key = "chat_history", return_messages=True)
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(), memory=memory)
    return conversation_chain

def user_input(user_question):
    response = st.session_state.conversation({'question': user_question})
    st.session_state.chatHistory = response['chat_history']
    for i, message in enumerate(st.session_state.chatHistory):
        if i%2 == 0:
            st.write("Human: ", message.content)
        else:
            st.write("Bot: ", message.content)
def main():
    st.set_page_config("GreenThread Consulting")
    st.header("GreenThread Consulting Chat")
    user_question = st.text_input("Ask a Question on the sustainability of our company?")
    if "conversation" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.conversation = None
    if "chatHistory" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chatHistory = None
    if user_question:
        user_input(user_question)
    with st.sidebar:
        st.title("Settings")
        st.subheader("Upload your Documents")
        pdf_docs = st.file_uploader("Upload your invoice and Click on the Process Button", accept_multiple_files=True)
        if st.button("Process"):
            with st.spinner("Processing"):
                raw_text = get_pdf_text(pdf_docs)
                text_chunks = get_text_chunks(raw_text)
                vector_store = get_vector_store(text_chunks)
                st.session_state.conversation = get_conversational_chain(vector_store)
                st.success("Done")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `It suggests installing fairs-cpu and gpu and none of it works.`. Did you get an error message running these commands? I think faiss also does not support python 3.12 yet.

Comment: @FlyingTaller I got an error installing both. BTW, tried in on 3.7, still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I solved this issue, by creating a new virtual environment and pip install faiss-cpu first. THen I follow the other packages I am using. Also FAISS is a subclass of the module faiss, which means you could either

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
```

or call this in your code:

```
faiss.FAISS(text, embeddings)
```

---

Same issue here. How did you install faiss-cpu? From Conda-forge? As is have understood from the official faiss site, that is the recommended way to install.

Interestingly, when opening a python process, I can manually import the package using the line:

```
from langchain_community.vectorstore import FAISS
```

I when calling FAISS i get the key of a valid class. Same happens when calling the function without text, embeddings parameters in the streamlit script. As soon as I add the arguments, I get the importError. Sadlly I cannot offer a solution, as I am still struggling with the same issue.